# very basic isc-dhcp server config issues

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I hope someone can see what I'm missing here.  Im currently trying to configure a offline lab and needing to have the main server provide DHCP.  The main server is currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I've installed isc-dhcp and attempted to configure it.  yet the server continues to fail on start up.

this is the dhcpd config file

```
# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#
# Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
# configuration file instead of this file.
#

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "hmilab.lan";
option domain-name-servers ns1.hmilab.lan, ns2.hmilab.lan;

default-lease-time 3600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
#log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
  range 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.200;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option subnetmask 255.255.255.0;
  option domain search "hmilab.lan";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1
}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
#  option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
#  option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.224;
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.example.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.example.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
```

This is the isc-dhcp-server file

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="eno1"
#INTERFACESv6=""
```

Every time I attempt to restart the service and then check the status i get this.

```
~$ sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-10-20 12:45:01 CDT; 2s ago
     Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
  Process: 6174 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then CONFIG_FILE=/etc/
 Main PID: 6174 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]:
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]:
Oct 20 12:45:01 HMIServer dhcpd[6174]: exiting.
```

Any help pointing out what the heck I'm missing would be awesome.

*EDIT*

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-10-16 22:11:35 CDT, end at Tue 2020-10-20 15:44:00 CDT. --
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer sh[7101]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer sh[7101]: exiting.
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 38: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0: bad subnet
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]:                                         ^
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]:
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]:
Oct 20 13:47:40 HMIServer dhcpd[7101]: exiting.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer systemd[1]: Started ISC DHCP IPv4 server.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.5
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.5
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: All rights reserved.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: All rights reserved.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 38: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0: bad subnet
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 38: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0: bad subnet num
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]:                                         ^
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer sh[7176]: exiting.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]:                                         ^
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]:
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]:
Oct 20 13:48:27 HMIServer dhcpd[7176]: exiting.
```

Comment: Run `sudo journalctl -u isc-dhcp-server.service -l 50` and put the output into your question as an edit.  Your systme says there's conf file errors and probably says what they are earlier in the error output.

Comment: Hey Thomas,  entering that command only returned a error

Failed to add match '50': Invalid argument

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl -n 50 -u isc-dhcp-server.service` - hard to type on a phone lol.

Comment: Hey Thomas,  i just posted the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `;` after

```
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.  I've made that change  and it's still failing.  do you by chance see anything else incorrect with my config file?

Answer (score 0):

Your subnet is wrong.

subnet 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0

Should be

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0

Hope it worked!